# Two different owners on same computer with MetaMask Wallet?

Tags: wallets, metamask

Is this possible?
I have a MetaMask wallet working fine. A friend w/o computer - can I set him up with MetaMask on my system - but obviously not my account. If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If you don't want the other user potentially having access to your account:*

You could:

- Setup another user on the OS
- Use a separate chrome profile within the same browser
- Use a separate browser, such as Firefox
- Or anything similar.

*If you don't mind the other user potentially having access to your account:*

In Metamask, click the colourful circle in the top right of the UI, and there will be a dropdown that says "Create account".

Comment: I don't want them to have access to my account. Doing that, they would have access to buy and send.

Comment: You could set up a new google chrome profile for them if you wanted? Then I believe Metamask should act independently of yours, other than that you could make another OS user (like a Windows account) for them and install chrome / Metamask fresh.

Comment: This is what I did. Also firefox works as its separate from chrome - so can also set up a separate MetaMask wallet there. Thanks. Put your comment answer in an "answer" and I will set it as the chosen one.

Comment: I have edited the original answer.